# Computing $H^*(BDiff(W_{\infty},D^{\infty});\mathbb{Q})$ via Mumford-Morita-Miller classes

Tags: cohomology, moduli-spaces, rational-homotopy-theory

Galatius and Randal-Williams proved the following generalized Mumford conjecture in their joint paper, ["*Stable Moduli spaces of High Dimensional Manifolds*"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1201.3527.pdf). For each characteristic class of oriented $2n$-dimensional vector bundles $c\in H^{2n+k}(BSO(2n))$, one can define the associated generalized Mumford–Morita–Miller class of a smooth fiber bundle $\pi: E\to B$ with oriented
$2n$-dimensional fibers as $\kappa_c(E)=\pi_!(c(T_vE))\in H^k(B),$
where $T_v(E) = Ker(D\pi)$ is the fiberwise tangent bundle of $\pi$. When the fiber is taken to be $W_g=\#^g S^n\times S^n$, the connected sum of $g$ copies of $S^n\times S^n,$ there is a corresponding universal class $\kappa_c\in H^k(BDiff(W_g, D^{2n}))$
which for $k>0$ is compatible with increasing $g$.

**Theorem** (Galatius-R-W) Let $2n>4$ and let $\mathcal{B}\subset H^*(BSO(2n);\mathbb{Q})$ be the set of monomials
in the classes $e, p_{n−1}, p_{n−2},...,p_{\left\lceil\frac{n+1}{4}\right\rceil}$ of total degree greater than $2n$. Then the
natural map $$\mathbb{Q}[\kappa_c|c\in\mathcal{B}]=\lim_{\longleftarrow g}H^*(BDiff(W_g,D^{2n});\mathbb{Q})$$ is an isomorphism.

---

> I would like to determine the stable cohomology $$\lim_{\longleftarrow g}H^*(BDiff(W_{g},D^{\infty});\mathbb{Q}).$$ Under the the isomorphism of G-R-W, this reduces to determining the MMM classes $\kappa_c$ and the classes $e,p_{\infty}$. How do I determine such classes? Moreover, is letting $n\to\infty$ in this construction permissible?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the limit in your boxed question indexed over?

Comment: Over $g$. @ArunDebray

Comment: @OscarRandal-Williams Do you think you would be able to help me here, seeing as you developed the theory?

Comment: Right, but $g$ doesn't appear in its expression. Did you mean $\varprojlim_g H^*(\mathit{BDiff}(W_g, D^{2n}); \mathbb Q)$ or $\varprojlim_g H^*(\mathit{BDiff}(W_\infty, D^\infty); \mathbb Q)$?

Comment: Oh, I see. Sorry, that is my mistake; I meant the former with $n=\infty$. @ArunDebray

Comment: If you mean to take the limit as $n$ goes to $\infty$ you need a way to map diffeomorphisms of the $n$-dimensional manifolds $W^n_g$ to diffeomorphisms of the $(n+1)$-dimensional manifolds $W_g^{n+1}$.  It seems unlikely that any interesting map like this could exist.  What map do you have in mind?

Comment: Hello Dr. Hatcher! I believe such a map is described in [Definition 1.1 of this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1203.6830.pdf). It uses a slightly different notation; however, I think the maps are equivalent (I am probably wrong, however). @AllenHatcher

Comment: In Definition 1.1 of that paper the dimension of the manifold $W_g$ (which is $2n$, not $n$ as I mistakenly said in my previous comment) is fixed and one is considering embedded submanifolds of ${\mathbb R}^N$ diffeomorphic to $W_g$.  Then one lets $N$ go to infinity via the natural inclusion of ${\mathbb R}^N$ in ${\mathbb R}^{N+1}$, so submanifolds of ${\mathbb R}^N$ are regarded as submanifolds of ${\mathbb R}^{N+1}$.  However the dimension $2n$ of the submanifolds is not changing.  There is no natural way to let $n$ go to infinity in this construction.

Comment: I see, thanks so much for your help! @AllenHatcher

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "compute the MMM classes".  The definition of $\kappa_c$ is given on page 2 of the paper you link to, and the statement of the theorem is that those classes generate and are algebraically independent, as $c$ ranges over the set $\mathcal{B}$.  I don't think there's more to say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Dr. Hatcher, the dimension of the manifold $W_g$, $2n$, is fixed and one considers embedded submanifolds of $\mathbb{R}^N$ diffeomorphic to $W_g$. Then one lets $N$ go to infinity via the natural inclusion of $\mathbb{R}^N$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, so submanifolds of $\mathbb{R}^N$ are regarded as submanifolds of $\mathbb{R}^{N+1}$. However the dimension $2n$ of the submanifolds is not changing. Thus, there is no natural way to let $n$ go to infinity in this construction.